# Algebraic extension of rational functions

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

Let $k\subset F\subseteq k(X)$ be chains of field extension, prove that $k(X)/F$ is algebraic.

"Proof:"
Let $y\in F\setminus k$ then $y=\frac{P(X)}{Q(X)}$ with $P\notin k$ or $Q\notin k$.

It sufficies to show that $k(X)/k(y)$ is algebraic, because this implies that $k(X)/F$ is algebraic.

Let $r(T)=P(T)-\frac{P(X)}{Q(X)}Q(T)\in k(y)[T]$, then $r(X)=0$, thus $k(X)$ is algebraic over $k(y)$.

Is correct?.

Thank you all.

Comment: It's close, but you're missing details at the end.  You're using more about $P$ and $Q$ than just that they aren't both in $k$. (e.g. something bad happens when $P(X)=Q(X)=X$.

Comment: But $y\in F\setminus k$ implies $P(X)\neq{Q(X)}$; no?

Comment: Sure it does.  Since nothing like this appears in your proof, however...